# Does an evaluation install of Windows Server Essentials get Feature updates?

Tags: windows-update, windows-server-2016

I've installed and activated an evaluation copy of Windows Server Essentials 2016 from the Microsoft Evaluation Centre:

> 14393.0.161119-1705.RS1_REFRESH_SERVERESSENTIALS_OEM_X64FRE_EN-US.iso

After installation, the *About Your PC* screen shows that the *Version* is **1607** and the *OS Build* is **14393.447** and in *System Information* the *Version* is **10.0.14393 Build 14393**

Windows Update runs and updates with **KB4343884** (which is the August 30, 2018 and latest Cumulative Update for 1607 at the time of posting) and leaves me with an *About Your PC* *Version* of  **1607** and *OS Build* of **14393.2457** and in *System Information* the *Version* is still **10.0.14393 Build 14393**.

I was expecting a feature update to become available via Windows Update, but none is found. Is that because it's an evaluation version? Is there a way to force a feature update to whatever version the latest feature update for Windows Server Essentials 2016 is?

Answer (score 1):

Windows Server 2016 does not receive feature updates the same way as Windows 10.

There are now two types of release channels for the Windows Server product.

1. Long Term Servicing Channel (Called Windows Server 2016)
2. Semi-Annual Channel (Called Windows Server).

It is essentially two different products for different purposes.

“Windows Server 2016” functions like the Windows Server we all know. It is updated only when you install the next major version (2019?).  It is the long-term use, stable and fully featured version of Windows Server.

“Windows Server” is a software-as-a-service model similar to Windows 10. It is only available through special channels. It can only be installed in Server core mode (no GUI). And, it is primarily designed for customers who need to innovate quickly and need new features often.

They can not upgrade each other nor can you switch from one mode to another.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/semi-annual-channel-overview

Comment: So, for example, the "Windows Server 2016" August 30, 2018 update [KB4343893](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4343893) for [1709](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4043454) is _actually_ for the "Windows Server" product and _not_ the "Windows Server 2016" product, as it's impossible for "Windows Server 2016" to be at the 1709 feature version?

Comment: @ThunderFrame yes, you need the equivalent update here: https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/ScopedViewInline.aspx?updateid=a87d3b1b-1ab8-400a-9334-0c14b2afe657

Comment: @ThunderFrame btw, these are cumulative updates - not feature updates. They wouldn’t take you to 1709 in any case.

Comment: thanks. Yes, I follow now. Same old naming nightmares that I'm used to from MS. So there's Windows Server 2012, 2012 R1,  and 2012 R2. And now there's WinSvr 2016 1607 which shares a release date and version with Windows 10 1607, but where Windows 10 clients can be older and newer in any of 1607, 1703, 1709 or 1803. People on the semi-annual channel have "Windows Server" which doesn't have a year moniker, but does have a version moniker, and yet updates are explicitly marked as being for WinSvr 2016, despite being ,_only_ for semi-annual WinSvr users and ,_not_ WinSvr16 users